# Relationship between semiconvexity and Lipschitz continuity

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

The following is written in the book I read:

> Let $T>0$ and $f:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a semiconvex function in $[0,T]$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in $[0,T]$.

I know the proof that $f$ is *locally* Lipschit continuous in $(0,T)$.
I however have no idea to prove the above statement: the argument I know does not work for this.
More precisely, I don't know how to prove that $f$ is Lipschitz contiuous also near endpoints $x=0,T$.

I'm glad if you give some hints or proof.

Thank you in advance.

---

A function $f$ is called semiconvex if $x\mapsto f(x)+\frac{1}{2}C|x|^2$ is convex for some constant $C>0$, and it is also equivalent to that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
af(x)+(1-a)f(y)\ge f(ax+(1-a)y)+\frac{1}{2}Ca(1-a)|x-y|^2
$$ 
for all $x,y$ and $a\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't know what "semiconvex" means. But a _convex_ function need not even be _continuous_ at the endpoints...

Comment: So a convex function is semiconvex, as one would expect. Then like I said, what you're trying to prove is simply false. Let $f=0$, except that $f=1$ at the endpoints.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I added the definition of semiconvex functions. I understand what you say, but it seems to hold the above statement...

Comment: It seems to hold? I gave a counterexample.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, I replied to your first comment. okey, I'm trying to find some counter examples.

Comment: ??? I _gave_ a counterexample already. Let $f=0$ in the interior and $f=1$ at the endpoints.

Comment: oops, I have missed your example. Mmm, that's exactly counter example. So the book is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For a continuous counterexample, consider a function whose graph is a  lower-semicircle. It is obviously convex but its slope blows up at each boundary. This tells us we can expect only local Lipschitz continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Just to get an "answer" into the record: The statement is false. A counterexample is given by setting $f=0$ in the interior and $f=1$ at the endpoints.